# Styling of Navigation Menu WP for Guest vs. Logged In User

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I have a problem with a Wordpress website I'm creating for a church. They'd like a seperate part only their members can see. I installed the plug-in WP-Members and created two menus, one for guests (not-logged-in-users) and for users (logged-in-users). I put in some code into the header.php, telling it to show logged-in-users one menu and not-logged-in-users the other. So far so good.

Problem is that the styling changes when a user logs in. A not-logged-in-user sees the navigation menu the way it is supposed to be. When a user logs in, the sub-indicators disappear, auto width doesn't work and the slider, just beneath the navigation menu also magically stops working. This makes me believe it might be a conflict with two plug-ins, or something like that

Code i used to show guest one menu and users the other:

```
<div id="navigation" class="clearfix">
  <?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'main nav',
        'menu' => 'logged-in-menu',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'menu_class' => 'sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow',
        'fallback_cb' => 'default_menu'
    ));
    } else {
      wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'main nav',
       'menu' => 'logged-out-menu',
       'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
       'menu_class' => 'sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow',
       'fallback_cb' => 'default_menu'
    ));
    }   
   ?>
</div>
```

The website is www.vineyardkollumerzwaag.nl/nieuw/

Username: Test
Password: test

Comment: Fixed the problem by deactivating the plugin Jetpack by Wordpress. Not sure what exactly caused the error, but after shutting Jetpack down, everything returned to normal.

Answer (score 1):

When logged in I'm seeing a JavaScript error coming from the script /wp-content/mu-plugins/notes/admin-bar-rest.js - the error is that an Object does not have the method 'on'

Looking a bit closer, you are including jQuery version 1.6.2, .on() was added to jQuery in version 1.7 - try updating the version of jQuery included in your site to 1.7+ and that should fix the issue

Comment: I updated the jQuery version to the newest (1.8.3), but it didn't help, unfortunately. Same errors. Resolved the problem now however. Started deactivating plug-ins and Jetpack by Wordpress seems to be the culprit. Deactivated it and everything is ok now. Thanks anyway!